# I cannot set a value on kendo multiselect using a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, kendo-ui

Hi I want to set a value on kendoui multiselect if it comes from a variable it wont display but if I set it direct to the method it does display. If I do this multiselect.value(["11","22","33"]) it will work but I want it to set it from a ajaxcall. Below is not working.

```
var multiselect = $("#cboresponsibles").data("kendoMultiSelect");
var value = multiselect.value();
var res = "";
res =  "'112','60','106'";

multiselect.value([res]);
```

Comment: Hint: version that works sets array with 3 strings, version that doesn't sets array with one string `"'112','60','106'"`

Comment: That is not an array, my friend. This would be a valid array: `res =  ['112','60','106']`.

Comment: Thank you so much DontVotemeDown I solved my problem.